# Git в Visual Studio Code показывает 10000 изменений. Как их удалить?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Я новичок в Visual Studio Code и мне в Git высвечивается 10000 изменений. Нажимая на кнопку Discard All Changes, мне высвечивается только такое уведомление. Что мне делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может у вас не добавлена папка `node_modules` в `.gitingore`? Или на чем вы там пишите.. Это бы убрало столько изменений, наверное.

Answer (score 0):

**Discard All Changes** означает **Удалить все новые файлы** — этого точно не надо делать.

Проверьте в каком каталоге вы инициализировали репозиторий.
И создайте файл .gitignore, в котором опишите все папки которые вам не надо добавлять в репозиторий. Тогда не будете видеть ненужные изменения.